# issue with image cache in getting image back firebase swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

[image][[image]][!I want load image from download url from firebase using image cache how can I can create an inheritance  where my image gets loaded I guess I am missing OOP concept somewhere. my image view is swipe label, how too create an instance where I can display the image on my view.

import UIKit

import Firebase

class swipeLabelViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var UserAgeText: UILabel!


var user:User? {

    didSet {


        let userNameSwipe = user?.userName

        userNameLabel.text = userNameSwipe

        let userAgeSwipe = user?.userAge

        UserAgeText.text = userAgeSwipe

        guard let profileImageUrl = user?.profileImageUrl else {
```

return }
            profileImageView.loadImage(with: profileImageUrl)

```
        print(profileImageUrl)

  //  let userFetchedImage = user?.profileImageUrl

     //   swipeLabel.image = userFetchedImage

       // self.swipeLabel.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: profileImageUrl)

     }
}
var profileImageView: CustomImageView = {


    let iv = CustomImageView()


    return iv

}()


var imageI : UIImage!
```

// var swipepic = CustomImageView()

```
@IBOutlet weak var swipeLabel: UIImageView!


@IBOutlet weak var userNameLabel: UILabel!




override func viewDidLoad() {


    super.viewDidLoad()


   swipeLabel.image = imageI


    let gesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:
```

## selector(wasDragged(gestureRecognizer:)))

```
 swipeLabel.addGestureRecognizer(gesture)



 fetchCurrentUserData() 


    }
```

// user model class``

```
class User {

// attributes getting users info  so i can set up  from  firebase





var userName:String!


var userAge:String!


var uid:String!


var profileImageUrl: String!
```

init (uid:String,dictionary:Dictionary) {

```
self.uid = uid

if let userName = dictionary [ "userName" ] as? String{


    self.userName = userName

}

if let userAge = dictionary [ "userAge" ] as? String{


    self.userAge = userAge
}
```

if let profileImageUrl = dictionary["profileImageURL"] as? String {

```
  self.profileImageUrl = profileImageUrl
```

}

```
}
}
```

// and lastly image cache class customImageView

import Foundation

import UIKit

var imageCache = String: UIImage

class CustomImageView: UIImageView {

```
var lastImgUrlUsedToLoadImage: String?


func loadImage(with urlString: String) {


    // set image to nil


    self.image = nil

    // set lastImgUrlUsedToLoadImage


    lastImgUrlUsedToLoadImage = urlString


    // check if image exists in cache


    if let cachedImage = imageCache[urlString] {


        self.image = cachedImage

        return
    }

    // url for image location




    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }





    // fetch contents of URL


    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

        // handle error


        if let error = error {


            print("Failed to load image with error",
```

error.localizedDescription)
            }

```
        if self.lastImgUrlUsedToLoadImage != url.absoluteString {

            return
        }

        // image data
        guard let imageData = data else { return }



        // create image using image data


        let photoImage = UIImage(data: imageData)



        // set key and value for image cache


        imageCache[url.absoluteString] = photoImage


        // set image

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            self.image = photoImage
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

}

no errors I just can't see image on my swipelabel UIImage

Comment: The question is a bit unclear. Also, you've not defined the var `profileImageUrl` anywhere and we also don't know what `loadImage' does. Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @jay check the model for user  profileImageUrl is in my model I have attached a picture thanks

Comment: Are you asking how to [Download an Image from Firebase Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files)? Also It’s a good idea to include code and structures as text, not links and images. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode)

Comment: @jay ok jay give me one minute I have uploaded all the code

Comment: See link in my prior comment. `Minimal` is the key word.

Comment: @jay ok  i will yes I have stored image in the firebase storage. no errors but I cant see the image on my app.

Comment: A couple of things; when using this site we need to be able to clearly read your code, so formatting is very important. Second thing is we don't want to see all your code - just the part that's not working. See my above comments and *please* review the two links. As is, the question is likely to get downvoted and possibly closed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a separate request to download the image from the url that firebase returns.  Here is a playground example:

```
//: A SpriteKit based Playground

import PlaygroundSupport
import UIKit

enum ImageDownloadError: Error {
  case failedToConvertDataToImage
}

func dowloadImage(from url: URL, completion: @escaping (Result<UIImage, Error>) -> Void) {
  let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
    guard let image = data.flatMap(UIImage.init(data:)) else {
      return completion (.failure(error ?? ImageDownloadError.failedToConvertDataToImage))
    }
    completion(.success(image))
  }.resume()
}

let imageView = UIImageView()
dowloadImage(from: URL(string: "https://res.cloudinary.com/demo/image/upload/sample.jpg")!) { [weak imageView] result in
  switch result {
  case .failure(let error):
    print(error.localizedDescription)
  case .success(let image):
    imageView?.image = image
  }
}
imageView.frame = .init(origin: .zero, size: .init(width: 300, height: 300))
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = imageView
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```

Comment: Thanks josh I will try that I wish I could up vote you but I can’t due to low points but thanks.